# how can i directly open browser to view html file from vs code?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

I write HTML and CSS code in `VS Code` and for previewing it I need to open file explorer then files then double click them to open them in my default browser.

it takes too much time. is there any proper way for this?

I have tried one live extension called live server but the problem with it is we have to click the 'go live' button any time I want to refresh the code.

Comment: once it is opened in the browser you can simply click the refresh button (Ctrl+R)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the mentioned [live server extension](https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server) is the one by Ritwick Dey..
[image]

.. then then after clicking `Go Live`, it will open your page in the default browser and reload it automatically, every time you save your work.
in some cases, it is helpful to save the folder containing your HTML to a Workspace, in VS Code, especially if you are writing an app using the MVC modal and the HTML and CSS are in subfolders.

Comment: This also works in remote SSH session - very useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can install an extension called open in browser.

[image]

After installation complete restart vscode and go to settings `Ctrl + ,`. Search for Open-in-browser setting and set your default browser as you can see below:

[image]

Then whenever you edit a html file, you can use shortcut `Alt + B` to open this file in browser.

Comment: how can I use with remote SSH?

Comment: what do you mean by that?